Is it possible for a company to dilute my shares to the point they are insignificant
Say I have invested in a company that has 4 outstanding shares. 3 shares are owned by the founder and 1 by me. Let’s say the valuation of the company is $100.
If the founder wants to increase her ownership share of the company by acting in bad faith, can she issue 96 more shares and sell them to another investor who is her friend?
The company’s valuation does not increase, and my share is only worth $1 now.
Is this a risk all investors take or are there safeguards to prevent this?

The founder can’t issue new shares, because only the company can do that, and it is a different legal entity from the founder.

@MikeScott: Let's try to answer the heart of the question instead of quibbling over semantics

@user541686 It’s not just semantics, it’s a key point. The founder is a human being who can act for his own selfish interest, but the company has a duty to act in the interest of all its shareholders, not just those who are also executives of the company.

This depends a lot on the country/state and/or the type of company and/or what the articles of incorporation say. In some cases issuing new shares requires unanimous agreement of all existing shareholders. There could also be thresholds allowing blocking such decisions (10 or 25% for instance, so a simple majority is not enough to dilute the others). There may be rules requiring the new shares to be offered to existing shareholders first (usually proportionally to their existing share). There may be different classes of shares, or not. And so on…

Related: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/58391/why-is-stock-dilution-legal

I always feel like I am screaming into the void here when I post this but, if you are investing, get some idea of what stock valuation method(s) you believe in. @str31 you have a better handle on this than a lot of the commenters and answerers.

Please don't put clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] the question to incorporate all relevant information and make it read well for someone who encounters it for the first time, then flag comments as 'no longer needed' once they have been addressed by an edit.  Thank you!  P.S. Please don't use the comments to write a short answer to the question.  Answers belong should be written as an answer, not in the comments.

@JimmyJames: By your logic non-public stocks don't have any particular value even before the sale, implying the OP can't even value their own stocks before the split. If you're gonna go down that rabbit hole, nobody is here to argue with or stop you, so please feel free to keep shouting into the void. But, to the extent that you can talk about the value of a stock, what I'm saying about is accurate about the sale and dilution.

@user541686 Non-public stocks are bought and sold so I'm not sure what you mean by that. And yes, there's no specific value to a company until stock is sold.  When a VC, for example, invests in a startup, if they purchase 10% of the company (10% of the shares) for a million dollars, that means it has an implied valuation of $10 million.  Any valuation of the company that doesn't involve a sale is an estimate.  Companies are almost never valued at their book value.  Usually, they are valued higher than book but sometimes less.  A cursory search shows the S&P is valued between 4-5 times book.

It will depend on how the shares are set up - if your 1 share is a separate "class" than the founder's shares as defined by the articles of incorporation, then yes it could be possible. If you've watched The Social Network you see (vaguely) how it played out for Eduardo Saverin and Facebook.

Is this a risk all investors undertake or are there safeguards to prevent this?

No it's not a risk for all investors, or even most investors. If you own common shares in a public company there's not a way for them to just dilute your shares. Corporate actions would dilute all common stockholders equally. Additionally, if something were done fraudulently to dilute shareholders, the affected shareholders could sue for damages.
These are very broad generalizations just to assure you that you do not need to worry about this if you are considering buying shares of a publicly traded company.
If you are getting shares of a startup that you are considering (or already) working for, then yes it might be worth having someone look over the corporate documents to make sure what you are getting actually has value (not just theoretical value, but value that you can actually realize by selling them if you want to).
It's also important to distinguish between diluting the percentage of ownership (which is usually not bad) and the value of that percentage (which is).  If you own 2% of a $100k company, and the company doubles its shares but also it's value (via the income from those shares) to $200k, then your percentage is reduced to 1% but the value ($2k) does not change.

Overall, a great answer.  I have to question "you do not need to worry about this if you are considering buying shares of a publicly traded company." Usually, and in general, I would say this is not a major concern. But, in bizarro WSB world, GME issued 75 million new shares recently which increase shares outstanding by around 20%.

@JimmyJames Good point, and I added a bit about distinguishing diluting percentage versus value. I'm not familiar enough with the GME case to know where it fits on that spectrum.

Fact-checking myself, I'm now seeing that it was 45 million shares.  Either I somehow read the number wrong (something I'm known to do) or there have been multiple issuances.  In any event, it's a significant increase so I think the general point stands.

@DStanley “If you own common shares in a public company there's not a way for them to just dilute your shares.”
It is true that everyone’s shares would be diluted, but if the value of the company does not increase due to that sale, then isn’t that problematic for all the existing shareholders?
Ruining their reputation might prevent a public company from doing this, but is it correct to say that a company could issue a large number of new shares and give it to a new shareholder (i.e., I’m not talking about splits where existing shareholders maintain their percentages)

@str31 Companies wouldn't just "give" shares away - they would sell them for the purpose of raising cash, which would increase the value of the company purely due to the increase in assets (maybe more if the expectation is that those assets will be used to earn even more money).

@str31 the company simply giving that large number of new shares to a new shareholder is likely to be prohibited (details matter), the others shareholders  are likely to have grounds to sue the board and/or that shareholder for damages, there tend to be very specific laws explicitly against this scenario. Selling them at market price would generally keep the value of the diluted shares similar, as they would own a smaller fraction of a company that's now more valuable.

This answer assumes the company is a public company. With four outstanding shares this is unlikely. In a private company (in England and Wales anyway) this is precisely why shareholders agreements (and occasionally articles of association) convey pre-emption rights and other forms of minority protection, which give far greater protection to minorities than relying on showing a breach of fiduciary duty. In contrast, these provisions exist by default for listed public companies (eg in the listing rules for the LSE and under FSMA).

@DStanley Raising cash through issuing stock doesn't increase the value of the company. It might, indirectly, if the raised funds are judged by the market to indicate a brighter future for the company, but in itself the increase in cash is balanced out by the liability to the new shareholders, exactly as if they had e.g. arranged a loan from a bank.

@aantia  If I own the only share (100%) of a $1,000 company and I sell another share of stock for $1,000, the total value of my company just went up 1,000. The value per share did not change ($2,000 over 2 shares is $1,000/share), but I'm speaking to the total value of the company.

@DStanley You've conflated two events - the company was re-evaluated at a higher price, and they also issued more stock, at the new, higher valuation. The fact that they now have more cash on the books is immaterial; the net value of their assets hasn't increased, because it's balanced out by the new liability. Normally you'd expect (ignoring the vagaries of market dynamics) that the share price would halve if you issued 100% more.
You might see your scenario e.g. if a company was doing very poorly and then suddenly announced a new investor, but that's certainly not the base case.

Stock is not a liability. The book (net asset) value of the company has increased.

Share dilution is a normal process that most companies engage in at some point.  Companies may issue new offerings as a way to fund operations and growth.  These new issuances absolutely dilute the existing shares.  However, this doesn't mean the value of your shares will necessarily decrease. If the company is growing and/or the market has a positive outlook for the company, the shares may stay the same price, or they may actually rise.  These new shares will reduce the percentage of ownership existing shares represent, though. Someone who holds a significant ownership stake may lose voting power through these issuances over time if they do not purchase a corresponding portion (to their initial ownership) of the new issuances.
There are cases, however, of shenanigans. In the US and likely many other countries, shareholders may sue for harm in such cases. I'm not a legal expert so I won't attempt to detail what would be considered a case worth pursuing, but there are definitely law firms who take on such cases.  For example, this law firm appears to specialize in such cases in closely held companies:

In a closely held company, shareholder dilution can occur when new shares are issued, resulting in a reduction in the ownership percentage and voting power of existing shareholders. This can happen accidentally or with the intent to try to ‘squeeze’ the minority shareholder out of the company (along with several other motivations). IN either scenario, the shareholder has rights and needs to move quickly to enforce them.

Note that in the above they clarify that this doesn't need to be intentional. 'Fraud' as mentioned in the question is also not required for dilution to be considered harmful to the minority shareholders.


The company’s valuation does not increase, and my share is only worth $1 now.

Not quite ...
Before the share issuance
The valuation of the company is $100. You own 25% of it, so your one share is worth $25.
After the share issuance
The worth of one stock is $25, so the new investor must pay $25 * 96 = $2400 for his 96 shares. The company, having taken in $2400 in cash, is now worth $2500 (the original $100 worth, plus $2400 in cash). Your one share of the company is still worth $25.
But what if the founder issues 96 shares for $10 each?
Then you can buy all 96 shares for $960. The worth of the company is now $1060, and you own 97% of it, or $1028.2. Since your original stake was only worth $25, and you invested only another $960, you've made a profit of $43.2. Effectively, you made money at the founder's expense.

This is only if there's a single class of shares. Founder dilution works through issuing new "preferred" shares to incoming investors.

This is the theory, in practice, to some extend, the valuation for dilution is not fixed and you might not have the right or money to buy the shares.

How did you buy the shares in the second scenario? The founder only offered them to their friend.

This is wrong. Besides what the other comments say, nearly all major companies dilute themselves regularly: they issue stock that is sold significantly under market value as compensation to executives and employees (employee stock options). This clearly is not available to outside investors. They also may take over a company by issuing shares and exchange them at a premium to market value for the other company's shares.

The idea that the value of a company's shares is the same as what was paid to the company for them is completely wrong and easily shown to be so. There are many ways to value a company but treating it like a piggy bank isn't one of them.

Also, issuing new shares doesn't increase the value of a company.  Surely, you've heard of the law of supply and demand and understand that a stock split decreases the value of the shares.  If all a company had to do to increase its value was to issue more shares, they wouldn't have to bother with things like revenues or profits.

@JimmyJames It does increase the value since the money obtained from the sale of shares increases the company's assets. Whether the money received is more or less than the market value of existing shares is another question.

@DStanley At some level, I agree, but I don't think it's useful to think about it that way. If you think that money that is put into a going concern is just going to sit there and be available later for you to withdraw, you should just get a money market account. The point of new share issuances is to take that capital and put it to use i.e., use it to fund operations or capital improvements. It doesn't make sense to think that a company can increase its PE ratio (assuming it has positive earnings) by 25 times by simply issuing new shares.

I did not say it affects the PE ratio, because it should not unless the offering price was different than the existing per-share value. We may be crossing on the per share value and the total value. Certainly the total value of the company increases simply due to the increase in assets (cash). Whether the per-share value increases or decreases depends on what the company does with that cash.

@DStanley I don't follow.  The 'P' in PE ratio is the total market cap i.e.: share price times shares outstanding.  If the number of shares goes from 4 to 100, and the price does not change, P goes from 100 to 2500 (as in the answer.) Assuming earnings did not change, the PE ratio must increase by the same proportion, per simple arithmetic.

@DonQuiKong Yeah, in practice nobody is ever going to agree that the company is worth $100 either (unless it's 100% cash).

@Barmar The founder can offer shares to specific individuals (who are not employees) at a price lower than market? You sure?

@JimmyJames It's semantics at this point, but issuing shares 100% increases the value of the company, because the company now has some extra cash in its bank accounts. It's why many financial websites report the cash-per-share of a company, and some investors value a company ex-cash (i.e., after backing out the cash pile). Of course, the company won't issue new shares just to sit on the $, it's planning to invest in its business. But until they do (after which the effects are unpredictable), and while the cash is sitting in a bank, their value has still increased.

@JimmyJames: Indeed the PE ratio will increase, but it's not clear that " The 'P' in PE ratio is the total market cap ".  It's equally valid to use "the ratio of (share price) to (earnings per share)", and in that case the numerator stays the same but the denominator goes down, again resulting in an increased ratio.

@BenVoigt You can calculate the PE ratio as earnings-per-share / share price or you can calculate it as the earnings / market cap. You'll get the same answer, and it should be obvious why that is.

@Allure So you think that the value of a company is simply the book value?  How do you explain that the market cap of the S&P is 4-5 times book value?

@JimmyJames did I say the value of a company is its book value? Whatever gave you that impression?

@user71659 I don't think the stock they's given as executive/employee compensation is issued frequently. They issue it infrequently as a block, or purchase it themselves on the open market, then dole it out as needed. So the stock isn't diluted on a regular basis, only when they run out of incentive shares.

Although some companies pay a certain amount of equity instead of salary, that's for the obvious reason that otherwise they'd have to pay $. I don't see how that's fraudulent. I suppose if this applied to OP's case and they didn't want to dilute their ownership, they could offer to foot the bill instead. (Or they accept they don't get to hire the employee.)

@Allure Your answer.  Show me where in your calculations you consider cash flows, growth, or some other aspect that would typically be used by someone valuing a stock.

@JimmyJames it's in the OP. I quote, Let’s say the valuation of the company is $100. OP did the calculations with cash flows, growth, etc, and arrived at $100.

@Allure And so let's say that was calculated using the discounted cash flow model.  Where in that model do you see cash on hand?

@JimmyJames you apply DCF and then you add the cash on hand. Please don't tell me you value a company that has a current & future earnings of $0 as worthless, even if it has $1 million on hand.

@Allure Where is that in the DCF? I don't see it. It's hard to talk about such hypotheticals but yes, a company with no revenues is essentially worthless. You realize that as a stockholder, you cannot access that cash, right? Companies have costs. If a company has no revenues, that cash on hand is as good as gone. Creditors have priority over owners in bankruptcy when liquidating assets.

@Allure If it's not a public company, the founder can sell shares at whatever price they want. Nothing in the question says this is a public company. There are just two owners, the founder and the OP.

Look, if you had a company with no operations, no liabilities, and was sitting there on a pile of cash, someone (or a group of investors) could purchase a majority stake, dissolve the company, and distribute that cash. But if the price to purchase that company was the same as the amount of cash, there's no point. You would need to get it at a discount to make that worthwhile.  What you are saying here is true from an accounting perspective, but I don't think that's a useful way think about investing and I think it leads to all the goofy ideas about dividends on these forums.

@Barmar When a company issues shares that it holds itself (treasury shares), it has no effect on the stockholders. That's because the dilution of assets created by the new shares is exactly cancelled out by the creation of assets the shareholders partially own: the stock. (Further, treasury shares can't be voted) It's only when the stock is no longer an asset of the company, e.g. it's issued to employees, where it creates a dilution effect. That's why the metric is shares outstanding which do not count shares held by the company.

@JimmyJames It's got a million dollars in the bank. If you're calling the company worthless, you're also calling that cash hoard worthless. Here's something else: immediately after issuing dividends, the share price of a company generally goes down. Why? That's not in vanilla DCF either. if the price to purchase that company was the same as the amount of cash, there's no point If the price to purchase that company was anything less than the amount of cash, you could make instant free money.

@Barmar the founder can sell their shares at whatever price they want, but can they issue new shares at whatever price they want?

@Allure What's the difference? The price of a share is what someone is willing to pay for it.

@Barmar if the founder sells their shares, there is no dilution.

@Allure They're not selling their shares. They have 75% of the original shares, so they can do pretty much whatever they want, because they outvote the OP. So they can issue new shares, and then sell those shares for whatever price they set.

@Barmar do you have any source for that? A quick Google search suggests otherwise - https://www.pinsentmasons.com/out-law/guides/shares-and-share-issues, Section 561 obliges a company to offer new shares first of all to its existing shareholders in the same proportions they already hold shares. In other words, it upholds shareholders’ right to be protected from dilution. If they are willing to pay the price asked for the new shares, they can have them.

@Allure I didn't know about that.

Seems like that's the most crucial thing, which should be in the answer.

@Barmar https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/104633/is-there-anything-that-stops-the-majority-shareholders-from-destroying-company It's an interesting question though, I asked a follow-up on the law SE.

@allure Yep, that's the ignorant nonsense about dividends I was talking about.

@Barmaar They are obliged to offer new shares to the existing shareholders but that doesn't mean the existing shareholders have the means or desire to invest more. I've been in a situation where I was a minority shareholder. I was given shares in return for my skills and efforts. The majority shareholder was the one with money. It would be easy for them to issue new shares and offer them to me knowing I wasn't interested in investing my money, just time. That kind of asymmetry is common.

@JimmyJames I suppose you don't think debt matters when it comes to valuing a company either. After all, debt doesn't feature in DCF either. Best wishes with your investments, then.

doesn't mean the existing shareholders have the means or desire to invest more Then they cannot complain about dilution. The new shareholder are putting in money, they are not putting in anything with worth.

Where is it written that because arithmetically, the worth of 'one stock' is $25, new investors must pay $25 * 96? That sounds correct only for extant shares in a publicly listed company and then only as a starting point for negotiation.
Aren't new shares quite different and depending on jurisdiction, issued at the fixed price set by the company's Articles?
Here in the UK, new shares would usually be sold at £1, regardless of any theoretical valuation.
Isn't that the whole point and doesn't it, yes, pull the rug out from under str31's investment?

@Allure Debt is a concern in relation to cashflow.  A company can have positive book value and go in to default if it cannot make payments. But debt is not necessarily bad for a companies value. There's a benefit to funding operations with debt because interest payments reduce the tax burden of the company.  Anyway, I'm curious how, with your theory, you would explain the recent events around gamestop.  The company raised 2.1 billion in June through new stock issuance. During the exact same period, the market cap dropped by around 3 billion.

@JimmyJames Sure, but you are valuing a company that has 0 cash flow and $1 million in debt the same as a company that has 0 cash flow and $1 million in cash. It's obviously not the same. As for GME, that stock is a meme stock for a reason. Its price does not move on fundamentals, it moves almost 100% on sentiment.

@Allure But yet the additional shares are generally sited as snapping off the momentum.   Based on what you argue, the additional shares should have no effect on the share price. How do additional shares cause negative sentiment?

@Allure "It's obviously not the same." Of course not. Ignoring non-liquid assets for simplicity, a company with no cash and no cash flow to make debt payments (or payroll) is already bankrupt. A company with 1 million in cash has some runway left. But that isn't the same as being worth 1 million to an investor. Investing in a stock is trading your cash for a slice of the future cash flows of the company. If that company has no cash flow and burns e.g., 100K a week, you are crazy to value it as having market cap of 1 million. That stock is going to nominal 0, if it isn't already there.

@JimmyJames If that company has no cash flow, no expenses, and $1 million in the bank, the worth is not $0 even though cash flow analysis might suggest it is indeed worthless. I'm not discussing this further, it feels like I'm being baited into a ridiculous conversation.

@Allure What's ridiculous is treating investment concepts like they are 5th grade word problems.  How do you explain that there are European banks that trade for less than their book value?  Not just momentarily but for years. Buying shares in a company that, from all available evidence, is about to be bankrupt is like loaning money to a drug-addicted in-law. You are not going that money back, much less get a return.

If the friend buys the shares for the previous valuation of $25, then the company will be worth $2500 (the original $100 plus the 96*$25=$2400), and you will own 1/100 of that, or $25, so you will have the same value.
If the founder offers the shares for less than the fair market value, then she is violating her fiduciary duty to act in the best interest of the shareholders, and this can be voided by a court.
You state that afterwards, your share is worth only $1, which would require that the founder collected no money at all from the sale. Such an action would be blatant fraud; there would be no argument to be made that it was made in good faith. In such a case, the founder could face criminal prosecution.
